# How to authorize android app to overcome "unknown source" notification while installation

Tags: android, installation, settings

Whenever I install my app on **new device** it blocks the installation giving ***"Unknown Source"*** notification, I can install it anyways by changing the settings to *allow installation by unknown publishers*. But I want to know how to overcome this issue by registering app or authorizing publisher or any other way that is without changing the phone setting application will be installed on new device without blocking it.

Comment: very simple. Make your app available in a *known publisher* for example `Google Play`

Comment: thank you that answers my question:) but i am not allowed to publish app in `Google play`, is there any other way?

Comment: I know there's also Samsung store. But besides submitting your application to an official store, you won't be able to simply bypass it, and that's for a very good reason. It's a security feature.

Comment: No of course not, what would be the point of the security check if a developer could just bypass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, Android blocks the installation of apps that aren't
>   downloaded from the Android Apps section of Google Play.
>
> You have to change setting to allow installation by unknown publisher.
>
> It is for the Security of device, there is no way to install unknown source application without changing setting.

Comment: If your app is on the play store and you distribute the same signed apk file that is on the store, is this still true?  Or does the installer just always check unknown sources?